# How to use jQuery to call ASP.NET AJAX Page Method?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, pagemethods

How to use jQuery to call ASP.NET AJAX Page Method?

Comment: Duplicate - this has been asked many times before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) by Dave Ward.